Interstitial Ad not reflecting Admob Settings
I have set frequency capping for ad unit few days ago to 3 impression per 1 minute. The ad unit is assigned to a campaign there is only one adunit for andoid and the frequency capping doesn't seem to work and ad is shown more than 3 times in a minute on each button click basically.
Went through all the forums and stackoverflow questions, most people mention waiting 24 hours but it's been longer than that. Is there any solution to this problem?

Update: is there a way to check frequency capping programmatically, does google expose these details in the app internally, we could check if capping is enabled then handle ad showing logic programmatically?

Can you try changing it to app level? https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6244508?hl=en#set-requency-caps-for-apps

@AmodGokhale Right now both are set to 3 minutes, should i disable a ad unit frequency capping and set app level only?

ad unit capping should work but since its not working.. try setting up it at app level.. If it works at app level please check your code to make sure correct ad units are set... check logs as well

Unfortunately, afaik we cannot check frequency with an API, but we can apply a workaround on client side with a persistent storage, for example, SharedPrefs:
val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("AdPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val lastShowTime = prefs.getLong("lastShowTime", 0)
val showsInLastMinute = prefs.getInt("showsInLastMinute", 0)

if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastShowTime < 60000) {
    if (showsInLastMinute >= 3) {
        // block ad
    } else {
        prefs.edit().putInt("showsInLastMinute", showsInLastMinute + 1).apply()
        // Show ad
    }
} else {
    prefs.edit()
        .putLong("lastShowTime", System.currentTimeMillis())
        .putInt("showsInLastMinute", 1)
        .apply()
    // Show ad
}

Also you can check if you're caching ad block state somehow.

Implemented this already, but client insists the control should be from admob configuration, so this solution is not ideal.

Before any thing I assume you have checked and rechecked App-ID and Ad Unit IDs by copy paste the actual IDs into your code, you cleaned up all test Ad Unit IDs, you've waited enough time (24-48 h) and you have tested on multiple real devices.
After this, it could be one of two issues:
First Issue:
You are testing only in test environment (Test devices, emulators, debug version of the app) and from my experience this may cause unexpected problems in a rare cases. in this case the proper way to test is to release the app into internal testing on Google Play and test with this version on new device. (if it does work, the problem in debug version, you should clean up everything)
Second Issue:
You have a problem making Admob unable to save the count impression of this specific user, this is usually caused by wrong way of integrating Admob to your code. In this case you should start new project with the same app ID and only test Ads (use admob test example). if it does work then you should remove Admob from your original project completely then integrate it again carefully.
